# Pytest fixture inside a class is not executed

Tags: python, pytest

I tried to evaluate the below code, but the fixture method 'newFix' wasn't even evaluated, so the console didn't print 'This is executed' when I tried the execute using the below command

> pytest -v --capture=no

But both Test1 and Test2 returned pass. It's supposed to print 'This is executed' before each test. But if I remove the class line, and make the functions general, then the fixture method 'newFix' is executed. Any idea why it's not executed inside a class? Please advise.

```
import pytest

class TestClass:

    @pytest.fixture()
    def newFix():
        print('This is executed')

    def test_Test1(newFix):
        assert True

    def test_Test2(newFix):
        assert True
```

Comment: Take a look at the docs https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#using-fixtures-from-classes-modules-or-projects

Answer (score 2):

The tests are non-static methods, so they should be defined as

```
def test_Test1(self, newFix):
    # Unit test here
```